# Experience Extractor extracts incomplete data

Tags: experience-analytics

I'm trying to learn how to use Experience Extractor however I'm running into an issue where the data presented on Experience Analytics and the data extracted are different.

Specifically I'm looking into the search keywords at April 24. Below is the data shown in Experience Analytics and SQL
[image: Experience Analytics Search Graph]

In SQL
[image]

The data shows that I've searched "en - test april 24" 12 times and "en - test" 1 time which I personally remember in doing so as well.

Now going to extracting the data, I've installed Experience Extractor, I added the connection string named "experienceextractor" with the same values as "analytics" as what the instruction https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor says. Moving onto the Experience Extractor from the Control Panel, since I'm not fluent in creating a custom JSON script, I'm using the UI from the dashboard page. This is how it looks like

[image]

downloading the result and opening it on MS Access here is what I was shown for visits.

[image]

Only the "en - test" search is showing and there are 2 blanks which I don't know where it came from. I was expecting "en - test april 24" to show up on the result. Is there anything I've missed on doing? Am I looking into the wrong data? Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2
I'm using ExperienceExtractor-0.3.1-8.2